# How to enter PHP data into <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/sheet.css" />

Tags: php, css, xhtml, mysqli

I have a script in which can successfully show OS and browser. I have made it so that it outputs a css script.  It breaks down the output to eight CSS scripts. (for now) This shows Mac, PC, and Ubuntu OS's with IE, Firefox, Safari, and Chrome as the main browsers. The script is in its infancy but it works for now. I am going to clean it up later.

Please don't tell me that the get_browser() works better, I am working on a server that won't allow it to work.

the CSS list is this:

- postcr.css
- postff.css
- postie.css
- postmcr.css
- postmff.css
- postmsa.css
- postsc.css
- postuff.css

The Script is this:

```
<?php
//Written by Matt Ridge
//Kaboom Labs LLC.
//Web Site to be Announced.
//This is a script that will identify the OS and browser you are using. This also has a fix in where Chrome shows up as Chrome, and not show up as Safari by accident. 



//Booleans to set OS and Browser to False.
$os = false;
$browser = false;
//Booleans for Web Browser & OS Functions.
$info = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$xp = 'Windows NT 5.1';
$vista = 'Windows NT 6.0';
$win7 = 'Windows NT 6.1';
$ubuntu = 'Ubuntu';
$ie106 = 'ie106';
$ie10 = 'ie10';
$ie9 = 'ie9';
$ie8 = 'MSIE 8.0;';
$ie7b = 'MSIE 7.0b;';
$ie7 = 'MSIE 7.0;';
$chrome = '/Chrome/';
$safari = '/Safari/';
$firefox = '/Firefox/';


//Operating Systems
if (stristr($info, "Windows NT 5.1")) {echo 'post';}
if (stristr($info, "Windows NT 6.0")) {echo 'post';}
if (stristr($info, "Windows NT 6.1")) {echo 'post';}
if (stristr($info, "Ubuntu")) {echo 'postu';}
if (stristr($info, "Mac OS")) {echo 'postm';}


//Web Browsers
if (stristr($info, "Chrome") !== FALSE) {stristr($info,"Safari");
        $chrome = 'cr.css';
            echo 'cr.css';}
elseif (stristr($info, "Safari")) {echo 'sa.css';}
if (stristr($info, "Firefox")) {echo 'ff.css';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 7.0;")) {echo 'ie.css';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 7.0b;")) {echo 'ie.css';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 8.0;")) {echo 'ie.css';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 9.0;")) {echo 'ie.css';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 10.0;")) {echo 'ie.css';}
if (stristr($info, "MSIE 10.6;")) {echo 'ie.css';}



//If OS or Browser not found in list.
if ($ubuntu || $xp || $vista || $win7)
$os = true;

if($firefox || $chrome || $safari || $ie106 || $ie10 || $ie9 || $ie8 || $ie7b || $ie7)
$browser = true;

if(!$browser || !$os){

echo'<strong>';
echo '<br />' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . '<br /><br />Administrator someone in your work force is using an unsupported browser or OS, please email this information to the developer of the web page you are using. It will allow your browser/OS combination  to be used correctly. Sorry for the inconvenience.</strong> <br /><br />Please copy and paste the text above and send it to your web administrator. It will explain everything he/she needs to do.<br />';}

?>
```

The script will tell a person to copy and paste a statement just in case they are using an unsupported browser, so the admin of the script could update the code.

What I want to do, is make this script output in here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/sheet.css" />
```

I want it to replace the sheet.css with the output of the script above.

I have it written like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/<?php require ('css.php');?>" />
```

I would like to think this is possible, but so far it seems it isn't. Can someone answer the last bit of my quandary. I can't imagine its not possible. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's so special about the CSS that you wrote one for each browser? Go with one version and support every browser you can. your future users will be grateful.

Comment: What is echoing? (or what's the error?)  It's certainly possible, and you're doing it fine - likely just not getting what you want echoed out, or not using the correct file path...etc etc etc.

Comment: Why do you have different stylesheets per OS/browser combination? it boggles my mind why someone would do that...

Comment: Put all your stuff in css.php in a function named lets say determinecss() and here do..<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/<?php require_once ('css.php'); determinecss();?>" />

Comment: The reason for it is simple. And people here may not agree, but if you look at web pages, they don't all look the same. People complain when IE destroys output, while it works in Firefox, etc... What looks correct in FF will not look right in Chrome.  If they do it won't look the same on a Mac or PC... that is why I'm doing it.

Comment: @Dave http://kaboomlabs.com/testbed/html-php.php  There is the link to the finished product. So far it's showing everything fine, just no formatting colors, or changes to text.

Comment: @MattRidge I know the point of this question is not whether you should do it or not, but as far as I know, creating cross-browser code is not that complicated and the visuals rarely change within browsers (except in IE or some CSS e.g. CSS3, but still degrades). What matters is the structure, and that the same content is accessible across all browsers. And it can be done without 8 CSS-files.

Comment: @MarttiLaine Yes it can be done with one CSS file, and I can do it as well, but the fact is that no one out there has done something like this, at least to a point where java is not used. I can use this document instead of doing CSS scripts making it work with images, links, etc.  I am showing that it can be used with CSS, but you can substitute whatever you want with the CSS aspect and put it in there, and it should work. Also, not everyone has browser_detection available on their server or wish to implement Java just for that function. Our opinions will differ here I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path it's actually creating is:

```
/CSS/%EF%BB%BFpostcr.css
```

Might be a lot easier to just set a variable in your file.  That way you don't have to worry about any extraneous data coming through.

```
//in the included file (shortened obviously)
$myCSS = '';
$myCSS .= 'post';
$myCSS .= 'cr.css';

//in the displaying file
... href="/CSS/<?php echo $myCSS; ?>"> ...
```

Comment: Ok, the file exists, the problem I am running into is that the color you are suppose to see for the background is a light blue.  Not white.

Comment: Which is weird, because http://kaboomlabs.com/testbed/CSS/ _does_ exists with the appropriate files.

Comment: It seems there are some invisible ascii chars in the href attribute.

Comment: @JanWesterdiep right, this is what is confusing me. using<?php require ('css.php');?> shows the css file you are meant to use, which is in the list above, in the CSS folder. Yet its not posting, and I don't know why.

Comment: @JanWesterdiep I am looking at the script on my computer, and I can't see where any of the chars you are talking about are...

Comment: Neither can I, but when I change the href attribute to "CSS/postmff.css" with Firebug I do get the right css file (blue background). What exactly are you echo'ing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6585/discussion-between-jan-westerdiep-and-matt-ridge)

Comment: Edited my answer - when looking at the source code in a browser, it didn't show the hidden culprit.

Comment: Yes, those things are what I was referring to.

Comment: @Jan (Your comments hadn't come through on my end yet)

Comment: @Dave Why would that be happening?

Comment: @Matt - not sure, but it doesn't really matter - you shouldn't be doing it the way you currently are anyway - there are so many issues that could arise - even a spare space would screw it up, let alone you're echoing "<strong>..." if it's something specific...etc.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry people this actually ended to be an accurate script. It works 100%... the issue was simple, and normally overlooked. 

I never removed the BOM! 

I had to fix the encoding issue so it would be saved as Encode in UTF-8 without BOM.

Now it works perfectly. 

Thanks for everyone's help, it was good to at least brainstorm, it got me on a path that I didn't think of.  I thought it was the overall code, when it was something as simple as the BOM causing the script to fail.